# Perl tricky regex conversion to be supported by older versions

Tags: regex, perl

I have working regex

`s/^[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|'[^']*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\\)'/\\'/gim`

that successfully escapes data in recent versions of Perl and fails in Perl 5.8.8 and older with the following error:

`Returned error in Perl 5.8.8 is Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^[^']'( <-- HERE SKIP)(F)|'[^']$(SKIP)(F)|(?<!\)'/`

This regex takes input data and makes sure that any `'` is escaped but NOT:

a) The first `'`
b) The last `'`
c) And not already escaped one `\'`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/2)

How do I convert my regex *to be compatible with old versions* of Perl?

#### EDIT:

Input data:

`%3 successful login (test test's test\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root`

Output data:

`'%3 successful login (test test\'s test\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'`

and not `.... (test test\'s test\\'s string) ....`

Comment: As you probably already figured out, Backtracking Control Verbs (like `(*SKIP)`) were added in Perl 5.10.  Is there a reason you need to code to work with older versions of Perl (instead of just requiring Perl from 2007)?  Just to confirm, you want `This 'is only 'one kind' of test' that exists` to become `This \'is only 'one kind' of test\' that exists`; correct?  (It seems almost backwards from the common practice of escaping the internal quotes.)

Comment: Yes, this is input data from user that has to go to `.js` file and JS string has to start with `'` and with `'` and all other `'` has to be escaped. In case user is trying to be too smart and escapes it, regex is taking care of this and NOT doing it all over again.

Comment: Your description seems to be opposite of my example text and so I'm confused.  Please include two or three lines of input and expected output.

Comment: @kjpires updated with explanations

Comment: The part about the first `'` and last `'` is a red herring. You don't actually know about any _other_ `'` until you locate the first and last.

Comment: How do you wish multiple-internal backslashes to be handled?

Comment: @kjpires just left them as they are!! :) _ikegami_ made one really work as expected and now _anubhava_. Regexs are different but it seem to produce exactly the same output.

Comment: Actually, the `\G` anchor is mostly misused in this case. Given the content is encased in unescaped single quotes is a no-brainer, 2 step process. Using `\G` you don't know the ending `'` until its too late. eg, it don't exist..

Comment: It's all about the logic. I suppose, it could be better design.. but it happened to be this way.. instead of re-building it.. I just made it work.. Escaping `'` is a boring stuff. Doing what I wanted is challenging.. It's all about learning for me. Thank you for your points, really!

Comment: If you want to escape data for Javascript, then I'd recommend the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module.  The `allow_nonref` option allows you to encode just a string (rather than an array or hash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $first_idx = index($_, "'");
if ($first_idx >= 0) {
   my $last_idx  = rindex($_, "'");
   if ($last_idx != $first_idx) {
      my $length = $last_idx - $first_idx + 1;
      substr($_, $first_idx+1, $length-2) =~
         s/\G((?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*)'/$1\\'/sg;
   }
}
```

You could do it all in one complicated substitution, but it might hurt performance in addition to hurting readability and maintainability.

```
s/
   \G
   (
      (?: ^ [^']* ' | (?!^) )
      (?: [^'\\]+ | \\. )*
   )
   '
   (?! [^']* \z )
/
   $1 . "\\'"
/xseg;
```

Tested:

```
var x = 'abc'def\'ghi\\'jkl\\\'mno';
```

becomes

```
var x = 'abc\'def\'ghi\\\'jkl\\\'mno';
```

Comment: Why not one string regex? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it escapes the string two time in case there is `\'` on the input! Besides this it's perfect. Can you make `\'` not to be escaped?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev finally you have it :) told you some pro perl guy :)

Comment: @ikegami Not sure about first part of your answer but regex seems to shine! Unfortunately I don't understand it, so far at least..

Comment: @vks ahh, you've been following! :D

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev, Actually, there were two bugs in the single substitution. Fixed. It's hard to read and hard to maintain. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: @ikegami - so you propose to use bulky `if` method? It's boring, I could do it myself. I really like your regex! Can you recommend me some good tutorial, so I could understand it better... or it's like with everything else.. just experience, that comes with time?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use this regex that will work in older perl also:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $string = "'%3 successful login (test test's test\'s string) alert for user's %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'";

$string =~ s/^[^']*'.*?(?<!\\)\K(')(?![^']*$)|(?<!^)(?<!\\)(')(?![^']*$)/\\$1$2/gm;

print "<$string>\n";
```

#### Output:

> `<'%3 successful login (test test\'s test\'s string) alert for user\'s %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'>`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX0nG4/3)

Comment: Hmm. Thanks you! It seems to work, with one little problem and that is see what happens if you put `;` at the end.

Comment: Interpreter in Perl gives an error: `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex`

Comment: What the OP is saying is that the first `'` might not be the first char of the string, and the last `'` might not be the last char of the string.

Comment: Not might! It is. See it as JavaScript string. Copied from above: This is input data from user that has to go to .js file and JS string has to start with ' and with ' and all other ' has to be escaped. In case user is trying to be too smart and escapes it, regex is taking care of this and NOT doing it all over again.

@anubhava This regex is better `(?<!^|\\)'(?!$)` and it works in `regex101.com` but when I write it - it gives an error. I write it as this, right `s/(?<!^|\\)'(?!$)/\\'/gim`

Comment: Still fails for `var = 'foo's';` and `var = 'foo\\'s';`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your help but Perl interpreter returns an error still

Comment: I have updated answer with fully working perl code and have tested it on my system.

Comment: @anubhava, my friend, thanks! Isn't `(test test'\s test\'s string)` should be `(test test\'s test\'s string) `.. On first one it puts slash on the other side..

Comment: Ah sorry I overlooked that part. It is updated now, please check.

Comment: @now, :) if there is no `'` in a string at all - it will escape last one! It's shouldn't! :D

Comment: I tested with `var abc = 123;` [on this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/19) and it didn't make any changes in last line. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @anubhava Could you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402769/

Answer (score 1):

Your probably overthinking this.
The trick is to consume even preceding escapes before that which needs to be escaped.

Then write that back as part of the replacement.
This always works with anything you need to escape.
This is simple and is the fastest way it can be done..

```
 #  s/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)'/$1\\'/g

 (?<! \\ )
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?: \\ \\ )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 '
```

I didn't do any format preservation of the outside `'`, but here is
a code snippet to grab the guts and just escape the inside `'` where
necessary.  The guts is passed to a callback (eval) to be escaped.
Simple really.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 $/ = "";

 my $input = <DATA>;
 print "Input:\n$input\n";

 sub callback
 {
   my ($core) = @_;
   $core =~ s/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)'/$1\\'/g;
   return "'" . $core . "'";
 }

 $input =~ s/^\s*'(.+)'\s*$/ callback( $1 );  /es;


 print "Output:\n$input\n";

 __DATA__
   '%3 successful login (test test's test\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root '
```

Comment: @sin :) no, no, then it escapes the first and the last `'`, along with escaping already escaped ( `\'`) input data

Comment: Well, as I said in my comment above `The part about the first `'` and last `'` is a red herring. You don't actually know about any _other_ `'` until you locate the first and last.` .. that qualifying part is not valid.

Comment: Oh.. you mean I should make regex to check only on what I need and make those 2 first and last `'` compulsory, after the regex's checkup? If so, it makes sense!! I hadn't been thinking about it..

Comment: Well, what you could do is `s/^\s*'(.+)'\s*$/callback($1)/e` then in the callback use the regex (above) on $1, where you return `'<converted>'`. I'll try to put up a code snippet.

Comment: I see. I just didn't look at it this way.. I was just doing it this way https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/blob/master/authentic-lib.cgi#L1546-L1551

Comment: In general, this is not a left - to - right thing. You can't correct a badly created delimited field this way because of the problem with closure. How you get the initial string is a mystery.

Comment: :)) The input is coming from a user. Look down there in a video and you will understand what I wanted to do. https://youtu.be/f_oy3qX2GXo?t=2m3s To make settings work both for Perl and JavaScript I write settings in simple and readable output (.js). Later, I make Perl parse that `settings.js` and read settings from it. It's crucial for `.js` to be valid, otherwise it will break. I make sure what ever user input is like - it will not fail. That's it.

Comment: I don't think JS does lookbehind assertions, but in this case there is a workaround. Find: `(^|[^\\])((?:\\\\)*)'` and replace `$1$2\\'`. Either way, a simple if ( input.match( /^\s*'([\S\s]+)'\s*$/ ) { var tmp = $1; /* do find/replace on tmp */ `input = "'" + tmp + "'"; } works with anything.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it good enough! :) What does JS is irrelevant. I build `settings.js` using Perl and make sure that it's valid whatever user's input is like!

Answer (score 0):

One-liner (regex inside of a regex):

```
s/^(.*'.*)$/my $x = $1; $x =~ s:\\?':\\':g; "'$x'"/me;
```

turns:

```
%3 successful login (test test's test\'s test\\'s test\\\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root
%3 successful login (test test's test\'s test\\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root
%3 successful login (test test's test\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root
This is a normal string.
Line ending in;
```

into:

```
'%3 successful login (test test\'s test\'s test\\'s test\\\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'
'%3 successful login (test test\'s test\'s test\\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'
'%3 successful login (test test\'s test\'s string) alert for user %1 from %2|%3 successful login alert|root'
This is a normal string.
Line ending in;
```

and should work for really old versions of Perl.

If you want to reduce the number of backslashes to always 1 backslash, change the `?` to `*` in the inside regex.

Comment: It wraps the string without quotes in quotes and messes with the last `;` Doesn't really work! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Ignoring strings without quotes is easy, but I don't understand the last `;` portion: it wasn't in your example.

Comment: Instead of `'w';` I get `'\'w\';'`